# How to override Spring Data JPA repository base methods?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have some entity type that needs additional logic on saving (to be precise, I want to save position at the moment of saving). I don't want to do it with any DB-specific features, like triggers, because I'm not sure what will be the data storage used in future.

So I would like to override `save()` method.

In Spring Data JPA documentation I can see two ways of providing own implementation for repository classes:

1. Extend base repository class and tell Spring Data to use it.
2. Defining an interface (in my case I assume `PositionedRepository`) with an implementation class (`PositionedRepositoryImpl`).

Problem with first way - I don't want to implement it for all repositories, only two entity types are positioned.

Problem with second way - I don't have access to base repository methods, so apart from position calculation I would need to somehow build all of the queries, normally provided by base repository.

Any way to extend base repository class just for specific repository types?

Answer (score 5):

Don't do that logic in the repository itself. Think about repositories as a dumb layer between java and the database. It just passes data from end to the other.

Instead you should handle that case in a different layer. A more intelligent one. The business logic layer.

See this example:

```
@Service
public class MyEntityService{

     private final MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;
     private final OtherEntityRepository otherEntityRepository;

     @Autowired
     public MyEntityService(MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository, 
                          OtherEntityRepository otherEntityRepository){
         this.myEntityRepository = myEntityRepository;
         this.otherEntityRepository = otherEntityRepository;
     }

     public void save(MyEntity myEntity){
          // do stuff with otherEntityRepository
          myEntitiyRepository.save(myEntity);
     }
}
```

Comment: Very good answer ! But `EntityManager` is not the best name as as it represents a very specific thing in JPA ! `PositionedService` to stay generic would be more clear :)

Comment: I expose my repositories as Spring Data REST endpoints, would like to keep it within the default Spring flow.

Comment: *I expose my repositories as Spring Data REST endpoints*. It may work but is highly discouraged. I would recommend to always have at least 3 layers between the database and the client: *Data access layer -> Repositores*, *Business logic layer -> Services*, *Communication layer -> Controllers*. That way you clearly have split up the responsibilities. *Communication* handles requests and calls the *Business logic*, which then calls the *Data access*. You will be grateful if you build your application like this

Answer (score 4):

you can :

```
public class CustomJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> {
  private final JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformationWrap;
  private final EntityManager emWrap;
  public CustomJpaRepository(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    entityInformationWrap=entityInformation;
    emWrap=entityManager;
  }

  @Override
  public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    //doing
  }

}
```

then main class add:
  @EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = CustomJpaRepository.class)

Answer (score 2):

As third option you can extend `SimpleJpaRepository` that implements `JpaRepository` and `JpaSpecificationExecutor`.
In this way, you could benefit from the default implementation of `JpaRepository` while being the ability to override these methods.

For example :

```
@Repository
public class PositionedRepository extends SimpleJpaRepository<Positioned, Long>  {

    @Override
    public Positioned save(Positioned positioned) {
           ...
    }

}
```

As fourth option you can also define your own `savePositioned()` method that uses under the hood the `JpaRepository.save()`.